# How to assign a value if in between values using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

my `df_created`:

```
created_date
------------    
2020-01-01     
2020-01-21     
2020-01-15     
2020-01-01     
2020-01-26     
2020-01-30
```

Notice that the above `created_date` is in random date order

I have another `df_ipsum`

```
id      date_start     date_end
---     -----------    ----------
100     2020-01-01     2020-01-09    
101     2020-01-10     2020-01-19  
102     2020-01-20     2020-01-29  
103     2020-01-30     2020-02-09  
104     2020-02-10     2020-02-19
```

What I want to do is assign the value of `id` from `df_ipsum` if the value of `created_date` on `df_created` `Data Frame` is between `date_start` and `date_end` so the new `df_created` looks like this:

```
created_date    id_2
------------    ----    
2020-01-01      100
2020-01-21      102
2020-01-15      101
2020-01-01      100
2020-01-26      102
2020-01-30      103
```

**What did I do?**

```
# using conditional expression: a if cond else b
df_created['id_2']  =  df_ipsum['id'] if (~df_created['created_date'].between(df_ipsum['date_start'],
df_ipsum['date_end'])) else False
```

when I do that I get this error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

however, my `dtypes` are identical, which is `datetime64[ns]` for all `df_created['created_date']`, `df_ipsum['date_start']`, and `df_ipsum['date_end']`

Could someone please help me solve this?

Comment: Actually, if you want to assign, then look at `pd.merge_asof`.

Comment: If the dataframes have different number of rows this will not work. I would use df_created.apply(lambda x: 
 np.argwhere((df_ipsum['date_start'] < x[created_date'])==1)[0]). This would return the first index of df_ipsum where the created_date is latger than date_start. You dont need the end_date for this exercise I believe, unless the intervals are not contiguously arranged. df_ipsum needs to be ordered for this to work. If your dataset is huge, this may not be the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.cut`:

```
df_created['id'] = pd.cut(df_created['created_date'], 
       bins=[df_ipsum['date_start'].iloc[0]] + list(df_ipsum['date_end']),
       include_lowest=True,
       labels=df_ipsum['id'])
```

Output:

```
  created_date   id
0   2020-01-01  100
1   2020-01-21  102
2   2020-01-15  101
3   2020-01-01  100
4   2020-01-26  102
5   2020-01-30  103
```

Comment: Thank You for composing the answer. It works.

Comment: Quick Clarification: Suppose `df_created["id"]` already exists but some of the values of  `df_created["id"]` are `NULL` then how can I update only the `NULL` values based on the same criteria?

Comment: `df['id'] = df['id'].fillna(new_series)`